# What CSS operators can I use to add more page names? Wildcards?

Tags: css, variables, operators, wildcard

I need to add more page name values beyond, "details".  What are my options?

```
        :host([page=details]) .menu-btn {
            display: none;
        }
        :host(:not([page=details])) .back-btn {
            display: none;
        }
```

I should add that the "page" variable is a js property in my html file.  I'm asking here because I don't even know what terms to use in my google search.

Comment: why the javascript tag?? (removed js tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Greg McMullen, for pointing me to [the documentation on attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors).

Below is the solution that worked for all page values beginning with "details-".  (Notice the vertical pipe in front of the equals and no trailing hyphen after"details".)  For example, values including, "details-1", "details-2", and "details-3".

```
        :host([page|=details]) .menu-btn {
            display: none;
        }

        :host(:not([page|=details])) .back-btn {
            display: none;
        }
```

Technically, in my case, the "page" variable is not a html element attribute, in the strict definition.

Answer (score -1):

The **`,` [CSS "combinator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors)** allows you to set up multiple selectors and acts as an "and"/"or" operator so that you can specify several selectors that should all share the same rule:

```
:host([page=details]), :host([page=details2]), :host([page=details3]) { . . .}
```

And, you can just specify the attribute itself (no value) to match all elements that simply have the attribute (regardless of the value):

```
:host([page])
```